# How to find out from a client if a smb/cifs connection is encrpyted?

Tags: linux, windows-10, encryption, smb, cifs

SMB can be encrypted in its different versions and can be activated as described on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-security . On the **server** the encrytion can be tested using the powershell as shown on https://www.rootusers.com/enable-smb-encryption-on-smb-shares/ .

But how can I test a (or several) smb connection(s) on Windows (and Linux) computers as connected **client** if the encrytion is really used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 10 clients use `Get-SmbConnection` from PowerShell with admin rights. It has extra fields which aren't shown in the default table format, but can be requested by name:

```
Get-SmbConnection | ft ServerName,ShareName,Encrypted
```

For Linux clients using the kernel *cifs* module (kernel filesystem mounts), I *think* this should be available in the file `/proc/fs/cifs/DebugData` along with other information, but either it's not actually there or at least not obvious. See the *smbclient* paragraph below.

For Linux clients using the userspace *smbclient* library (including GNOME's smb:// paths), there's no easy way of knowing. I would run a packet capture using Wireshark and see what happens when I read a file – the difference between plain and encrypted SMB packets is easily visible.

Comment: I am a bit late but for those who are looking for the Get-SmbConnection equivalent in macOS, the answer is: $ smbutil statshares -a